# Spring Boot Oauth 2.0 - Creating a Custom Authorization Server

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

I want to implement custom authorization server in Spring Boot. Found some articles around it but so far no luck. I want to authenticate based on user, password and a tenant ID. The default implementation works fine with user and password. However, how should I use the tenant ID for authentication and generating a principal that includes tenant ID as well.
 Is there any useful link that I should look for?